# Edits of old answers where the original poster's first notification is an upvote or downvote

Tags: discussion, edits

Update - SO servers were having issues at the time I posted this question, and the timing issue may have been related to SO server issues (shutting down / restart, server database errors, ...), which I haven't seen in quite a while. So the timing issue I'm asking about here may have been fixed now.

The main question: is there or should there be some waiting period for the original poster to review an edit before the edit gets approved?

If an edit is made to an answer, perhaps years after the original answer was posted, there is or was a **timing window** where the original poster starts receiving upvotes or downvotes on the edited answer before getting a chance to review the edit to see if the edit should be reverted or improved.

In the cases where the edit improved the answer, I don't see an issue, but if the edit degraded the answer, the degraded edit bumped the answer to the front page before the original poster had a chance to revert or improve the degrading edit.

As an example, one of my answers was degraded with the removal of a descriptive link which was a key part of that answer (explaining how name mangling is used in C++ to overload functions). I only noticed the edit due to a downvote, since the edit notification did not trigger an alert. I corrected the edit by restoring the descriptive link.

Again, the timing issue may have been related to SO server issues at the time which are now fixed.

Comment: Is the old answer now out of date/incorrect?

Comment: If the information in the answer is still correct, then I don't really understand the issue. Would you be complaining if the edit had caused upvotes?

Comment: If that's really the problem, remove the mention of downvotes from the question. It's making it look like all you care about is that you lost reputation.

Comment: Meta (and SE in general) *tends* to work better when you focus on one question at a time. That's why I'm trying to understand what *specifically* your concern is. If you're concerned about downvotes without comments, or "random" downvotes, that's irrelevant to the edits. You can get them after four years even without an edit if someone happens to have the same question as the one you answered or if someone adds a new answer. If an edit degrades an answer, that's completely different... and not even the situation you're dealing with here, where there was no real change to the answer at all.

Comment: @Catija - I updated my question so that it covers both up votes and down votes, yet the only responses I see are more down votes on the question, no new comments or answers posted since I made the suggested edit.

Comment: Likely because no one can see it. Most people view SE sites using the active page (main view).  One downside of this is that meta posts scoring -8 or less are hidden.

Comment: @Catija - and yet this question received 2 or 3 more down votes since the last update. In my case the lost rep wasn't the issue, as I'm well over 13,000 rep at SO. However, I've seen a few threads about SE/SO [being nicer to new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users?) and [explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes?). In my case, I'm less active at SO now.

Comment: @Catija - I updated my question again, to get more to the key point of  the timing window where an edit causes an answer to get bumped to the front page before the original poster has a chance to revert or improve the edit. The issue now is the question will probably not be seen due to the post score, but I don't want to create a duplicate question either.

Comment: @Catija - my last comment got lost, reposting it again: getting back to your first comment, the edit removed a reference and link to name mangling, which explained how C++ handles function overloading. Although the edit didn't make the answer incorrect, it did degrade the answer by removing a key part of the answer, and the timing issue was I got a downvote, and I don't recall getting an edit notification, or that the edit notification didn't show up until after the downvote. SO was having server issues at the time.

Answer (score 16):

Suppose someone edited one of your old answers, and improves it so much that you get a couple of upvotes after the edit. Is it fair that *you* get these upvotes instead of the editor?

If you think the edit doesn't improve your answer, you can always roll it back. There's also a chance that the edit bumped the post and brought it to the attention of someone who would've downvoted the post regardless of the edit.

---

Regarding your update:

> Is there or should there be some waiting period after an edit not reviewed by the original poster, before the edit is applied and the answer bumped?

For *suggested* edits, note that the author already gets a notification of a suggested edit on one of their posts, allowing them to take care of it on a short notice. For normal edits, first of all we 'trust' users with 2k reputation to make good edits (or at least edits which don't make the post worse). If you see a user repeatedly making bad edits, you can flag one of the edited posts for moderator attention (please include a thorough explanation, including links to the edits you've found). Otherwise, one of the points of making edits bump an old question/answer is that the community can review said edit, and roll it back if it's wrong. If we'd have to wait for the OP to approve, that could take weeks if they're on holiday, or forever if they've left the site. Meanwhile, a potentially very helpful edit is waiting which could've made many readers happy.

The current approach works quite well in general, and reflects the fact that everything posted here is in a sense 'owned by the community', but I can't help having the feeling that you hit one of those rare cases where somebody downvoted your edited post instead of rolling back the wrong edit.

Comment: @rcgldr: There's a difference between *making a post strictly better along the same lines* and *making a net improvement to a post by departing from the original idea*. The latter is not permitted except for the original author. (Editors can be penalized for bad edits, but aside from suggested edit automatic bans, the only mechanisms for this are rather coarse-grained and manual.)

Comment: @rcgldr That *one* person thought that the answer was a good answer doesn't mean that there is no room for improvement for the answer.  Even answers that the author of the question liked can still be improved via edits.

Comment: @rcgldr Sure, that particular edit was bad, but it has nothing to do with the fact that the answer was accepted, and it's not even that the answer couldn't have been improved (the later edits show that it most certainly could have been) it's just that the editor didn't succeed in making those improvements.

Comment: Worth pointing out it is likely whom ever issued the downvote was going to downvote no matter what, and all the edit did, was being it to the reviewers attention.  By reverting the edit you provided the person who issued the vote a chance to reverse it.  If the edit was in a review queue what I described is even more likely (depending on the age of the answer)

Comment: Yes, honestly your answer was improved, but seems only after you received a downvote.  The edit likely was the catalyst, but honestly, it was already a so-so answer compared to the other answer submitted 10 minutes before it

Comment: @Ramhound - My answer was the only one to explain that name mangling is how function overloading is implemented by most C++ compilers. I was only trying to clarify a comment made by Gene. I probably tried to edit the question back in 2014, but SO forum was having issues back then and I may lost an edit, and simply forgot about it until someone else made an edit to fix a typo that I normally would have fixed. Still my question here was meant to be more generic, but I now realize the timing window would be small (other person edits, downvote occurs, before the edit is undone).

Comment: I revised my question as suggested by Catija to get to the key point of the timing window where an edit bumps an answer before the original poster has a chance to revert or improve the edit.

Answer (score 12):

Editing shouldn't change the meaning of the post. Assuming that didn't happen here, the downvote is totally okay.

When a post is edited, it is bumped and subsequently viewed by new eyes. Those users can vote as they wish, it this case resulting in a downvote. I wonder how much you would have complained is it was upvoted after all those time.

Comment: The edit removed what explicit link about [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), and instead attached the link to a quoted comment, where the link wasn't clear due to the yellow background on quotes. Since there was no comment explaining the reason for the down vote, I can't know if the down vote was for simply bumping an old answer due to an edit where the down voter missed the fact that someone else had done the edit, or if the down vote was because the edit made the answer less clear.

Comment: I revised my question as suggested by Catija to get to the key point of the timing window where an edit bumps an answer before the original poster has a chance to revert or improve the edit.